# trying to send file to user using ASP.Net core 2.1. Response doesn't have AppendHeader and TransmitFile

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, system.web

I think I missing a nuget package but I can't seem to figure out which one.

I have `using System.web;`, but I only see Http under it no HttpContext.

Response is currently `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpReponse`

I've searched and searched, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

how do I get the correct one?

Thanks!

VS2017

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=SailBig.jpg");
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/images/sailbig.jpg"));
Response.End();
```

Comment: additional info: I'm trying to do this from a method that is in cshtml.cs that extends PageModel. That is where the wrong Response class is coming from. I've tried several nuget packages trying to get access to the classes I need, but no luck.

Comment: I was able to just return the file as the ActionResult, but it just downloads the file to the default download location without giving the use an option to save or open. Anyway to make this give a dialog for the user?
`var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(zipFile);
return File(bytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, zipFile);`